# How do I configure Tinymce to allow embed tags when editing html?

Tags: tinymce, embed

I would like users to be able to copy and paste embed tags for videos (youtube, vimeo, etc) into the html editor of tinymce.  I've tried every solution I can find on the internet - however tinymce always strips out any embed tags in the video embed code when I press update in the html editor.

Here is my current tinymce init script:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    extended_valid_elements: "embed[width|height|name|flashvars|src|bgcolor|align|play|loop|quality|allowscriptaccess|type|pluginspage]",
    theme: "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "code",
    media_strict: false
});
```

If I turn off tinymce's "cleanup" functionality (cleanup : false)...which I don't want to do...then everything works as desired

I've tried many versions of extended_valid_elements and other options but found nothing that works.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Shane

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For what it's worth - after much trail and error I learned that you must include the media plugin to get media_strict to work.  If this is documented somewhere I must have missed it.  Here is an updated init script that allowed me to insert embed tags via the html editor in tinymce:

```
tinyMCE.init({ 
    mode: "textareas",      
    plugins: "media",
    theme: "advanced", 
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "code", 
    media_strict: false 
});
```

This is known to work with tinymce ver 3.2.5 & 3.3.8 - but as noted below might have issues with tinymce ver 3.3.5

Comment: This works for me in the editor but when you submit the post data it encodes certain < and > signs as html entities. Everything I've tried in terms of the extra init parameters won't get rid of this. Any tips?

Comment: Hey Oliver - it appears that the latest version of tinymce (3.3.5.1) breaks the above config code.  A number of users on the tinymce support boards seem to have the same issue.  We recently upgraded for the table support - and the youtube embed functionality stopped working.  I haven't had time to fix the problem (again) - but will post the answer when I do.

Comment: Revisited this issue again today since our flash/video embed has been broken since we upgraded to tinymce ver 3.3.5 - Turns out upgrading to tinymce ver 3.3.8 fixed our problem.  Also updated accepted answer (above) with a bit more info

Comment: Also note, that `media_strict` is an option to the [media-plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:media), not TinyMCE itself.

Comment: +1, had this problem, searched google landed on this page, copy 'n pased it. **issue resolved in less than a minute** SO is such a great place

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to achieve this from a tinymce plugin then the following code can do the trick in the plugins init section.

```
ed.onPreInit.add(function() {
              // Allow video elements
              ed.schema.addValidElements('object[id|style|width|height|classid|codebase|*],param[name|value],embed[id|style|width|height|type|src|*],video[*],audio[*],source[*]');
            });
```

This is taken from the media plugin.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I also have the `iFrame fix` if you plan in including GOOGLE MAPS for example.

```
extended_valid_elements: "iframe[src|width|height|name|align], embed[width|height|name|flashvars|src|bgcolor|align|play|loop|quality|allowscriptaccess|type|pluginspage]",
```