# How to parse embedded videos from youtube, vimeo, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, embed

I'm working with Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 and I'm using TinyMCE with image and video upload functionalities.

I've figured out that when I insert a Vimeo video, it won't work, because it needs it's own iframe, as the following:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/16430948" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe><p><a href="http://vimeo.com/16430948">YOU! - Heart</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user1842450">KUSKUS</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

I'm now wondering how to show either youtube (which work just fine), vimeo, and other kind of embedded videos.

**Update:**

Searching on the internet I've found the following code, in the file `/plugins/media/media.js`, within `getType` function:

```
// Vimeo
if ( v.match(/^http:\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}vimeo\.com\/(\d+)$/) ) {
    f.width.value = '400';
    f.height.value = '321';
    f.src.value = 'http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=' + v.match(/^http:\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}vimeo\.com\/(\d+)$/)[1];
    return 'flash';
}
```

But it's not working for me. At least, all I see is that it's treating it as it was a common flash video, instead of inserting an iframe on the html for playing it (as it's done when you click the "Embed" button at vimeo.com).

Answer (score 0):

The iframe tag usually gets removed (cleanup) if you do not specify otherwise.
Add this to your tinymce configuration to keep iframes inside the editor:

```
extended_valid_elements:"iframe[id|class|title|style|align|frameborder|height|longdesc|marginheight|marginwidth|name|scrolling|src|width]",
```

[This thread might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625001/how-do-i-configure-tinymce-to-allow-embed-tags-when-editing-html) be of help too.

Comment: I've already added that line into my config file, but I think the problem is something else...and it may be that you have a drop down list to select the type of video (flash, windows media, real media, etc) and each of them as it's own embed syntax. So, I think that as there's no "vimeo" option (not a good solution anyway), the embed is the one that belongs to "flash" video type.

Comment: This works when you want to edit the HTML, but I don't want that. I want users to be able to upload Vimeo videos using the Media plugin, as they do with YouTube videos as well.